# Rails 6 includes objects by two models - joins instead of each

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've three models - `User`, `FakeBankAccount` and `BankAccount`. Last two are associated based on non-standard foreign_key like below:

```
class BankAccount < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bank_accountable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :fake_bank_account, foreign_key: :external_id, primary_key: :identifier, optional: true
end

class FakeBankAccount < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :bank_account, foreign_key: :external_id, primary_key: :identifier
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bank_accounts, as: :bank_accountable
end
```

Inside of the index controller I would like to display only `fake_accounts` that belong to a `current_user`. Basically I would do something like:

```
def index
  @fake_bank_accounts = current_user.bank_accounts.each(&:fake_bank_account)
end
```

But I don't think it's a good way to do so. I was trying to use includes:

`current_user.bank_accounts.includes(:fake_bank_account)`

But I'm getting AR collection of `bank_accounts` instead of `fake_bank_accounts`.

Comment: i don't know why you use `each` here, it should be `map`, right ? `current_user.bank_accounts.includes(:fake_bank_account).map(&:fake_bank_account)`

Comment: @LamPhan that's right, it should be a map but still... I don't think it's a good way to do so especially when you want to add e.g. sorting, pagination whatever. Then you'll end up with a rather long shitty code line - e.g. `current_user.bank_accounts.includes(:fake_bank_account).map(&:fake_bank_account).sort_by(:&id)` - I think there is a better way to do so

Comment: so you could use `has_many :fake_bank_accounts, through: :bank_accounts`, right ? it's just an convenient way to access `fake_bank_accounts`, it's actually your previous code, i just wonder why you're using `each`.

Comment: Unnecessary binding of the database only for one line doesn't seem ok to me, especially that my database has already a lot of such shortcuts. Using each was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rb
FakeBankAccount.joins(:bank_account)
               .where(bank_accounts: { bank_accountable: current_user })
```

This is basically the same as:

`has_many :fake_bank_accounts, through: :bank_accounts`